# How to change text when a button is pressed with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui, python-3.10

I'm trying to make a calculator with PySimpleGUI as a school project and I have made a basic GUI with it but I am struggling to make the buttons functional. I made functions for all the buttons.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def pressed_button_0():
    button0 = 0


def pressed_button_1():
    button1 = 1


def pressed_button_2():
    button2 = 2


def pressed_button_3():
    button3 = 3


def pressed_button_4():
    button4 = 4


def pressed_button_5():
    button5 = 5


def pressed_button_6():
    button6 = 6


def pressed_button_7():
    button7 = 7


def pressed_button_8():
    button8 = 8


def pressed_button_9():
    button9 = 9


problem = ''

layout_1 = [
    [sg.Text('Calculator')],
    [sg.Text(str(problem))],
    [sg.Button('1'), sg.Button('2'), sg.Button('3'), sg.Button('÷')],
    [sg.Button('4'), sg.Button('5'), sg.Button('6'), sg.Button('×')],
    [sg.Button('7'), sg.Button('8'), sg.Button('9'), sg.Button('+')],
    [sg.Button('.'), sg.Button('0'), sg.Button('='), sg.Button('-')]
]
sg.theme('dark grey 13')
window = sg.Window('Calculator', layout_1)
problem = ''

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == '0':
        pressed_button_0()


window.close()
```

i tried setting a text element as a variable which i thought would update when i pressed a button but that didnt seem to work, not sure what i did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `buttonX` is just a variable and nothing about the GUI, you have to call `elemet.update(value=something)` where the element can be found by `window[element_key]`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

keys = ['123÷', '456×', '789+', '.0=-']
all_keys = ''.join(keys)

sg.theme('DarkGrey13')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 16))
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Calculator', expand_x=True, justification='center')],
    [sg.Input(size=5, expand_x=True, key='-INPUT-')]] + [
    [sg.Button(key, size=3) for key in row] for row in keys] + [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Submit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Calculator', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event in all_keys:
        problem = values['-INPUT-']
        window['-INPUT-'].update(problem + event)
        window['-INPUT-'].widget.xview_moveto(1)

    elif event == 'Submit':
        problem = values['-INPUT-']
        print(problem)

window.close()
```

Comment: is it possible to explain how you did this, or where this is in the documentation

Comment: Find the method `update` of `Input` element here. https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#input-element